# Cannot `import smtplib`

Tags: python, import, smtplib

When ever I try to `import smtplib` in the Python interpreter, I get this error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name fix_eols
```

How can I fix this?

Edit:
Here is the full stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 46, in <module>
        import email.utils
    File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/email/utils.py", line 32, in <module>
        from email._parseaddr import quote
    File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/email/_parseaddr.py", line 16, in <module>
        import time, calendar
    File "/Users/aaronblock/Documents/programming/scripts/calendar.py", line 7, in <module>

    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apiclient/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
        from googleapiclient import discovery
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/discovery.py", line 38, in <module>
        from email.generator import Generator
    File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/email/generator.py", line 15, in <module>
        from email.header import Header
    File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/email/header.py", line 16, in <module>
        import email.quoprimime
    File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/email/quoprimime.py", line 49, in <module>
        from email.utils import fix_eols
ImportError: cannot import name fix_eols
```

Comment: Please include the full stack trace.

Comment: @horns I added the full stack trace

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to point out how to detect this kinds of errors (since it does happen from time to time):

Pay attention to the stacktrace. In this example, the problem can be seen in the line:

```
File "/Users/aaronblock/Documents/programming/scripts/calendar.py", line 7, in <module>
```

which certainly indicates wrong file being imported when we're trying to import a system-wide library.

Answer (score 0):

I had a file called "calendar.py" which messes up my Python environment because smtplib needs calendar.py in order to work. Deleting calendar.py solved my problem.